# What is the use of "jsonValidateReturn"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-validation-engine

I have tried to search for this inside jQuery and it's official websites but cant seem to get a tangible reasoning on this thingi... Am using `validationEngine.js` and while browsing though codes, I came accross this line: `errorNumber = data.jsonValidateReturn.length`   under `success` in the `else` close:

```
 success: function(data){
                        if(data == "true"){         // EVERYTING IS FINE, SHOW SUCCESS MESSAGE
                            $(caller).css("opacity",1)
                            $(caller).animate({opacity: 0, height: 0}, function(){
                                $(caller).css("display","none")
                                $(caller).before("<div class='ajaxSubmit'>"+$.validationEngine.settings.ajaxSubmitMessage+"</div>")
                                $.validationEngine.closePrompt(".formError",true)   
                                $(".ajaxSubmit").show("slow")
                                if ($.validationEngine.settings.success){   // AJAX SUCCESS, STOP THE LOCATION UPDATE
                                    $.validationEngine.settings.success && $.validationEngine.settings.success(); 
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                        }else{                      // HOUSTON WE GOT A PROBLEM (SOMETING IS NOT VALIDATING)
                            data = eval( "("+data+")"); 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            errorNumber = data.jsonValidateReturn.length //THIS IS THE WHAT AM TALKING ABOUT    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            for(index=0; index<errorNumber; index++){   
                                fieldId = data.jsonValidateReturn[index][0];
                                promptError = data.jsonValidateReturn[index][1];
                                type = data.jsonValidateReturn[index][2];
                                $.validationEngine.buildPrompt(fieldId,promptError,type);
                            }
```

I tried to google though and found the line repeated in several other different types of scripts....

It might be use full in my new projects but I would like to know what is it's exact use... is it part of `Query Ajax` or is it just a form of validation?

Thank you

Comment: Why the DownVote... Please add a comment first or say something before clicking the Down arrow... Thank you